# Programmatically connect Windows VPN invisibly

Tags: c#, windows, vpn

How do I write code to connect through Windows VPN client?

I want this process to happen invisibly during logon.

Comment: Good question for www.serverfault.com if you just want achieve invisible connection during logon, and not necessarily programmatically...

Comment: I will try to close this as off-topic (better on Server Fault). Due to its age it will not not migrate there (as far as I know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with code.  You can configure windows to connect automatically to the vpn upon logon.

Comment: oh well,but i need this to work like a logon script...can't configure manually.

Comment: I know this is old - but can you describe how?

Comment: It's better to post the answer here, since EE does not allow viewing of all comments (and thus, sucks).

Comment: Yes it does.  Scroll all the way down and the commets are viewable.  If you can't still see them, the search in google and click the cache link on Google's result and then you can see all the comments.

Answer (score 2):

The Remote Access Service API is what you're after, specifically the RasDial function:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377004(v=vs.85).aspx

Remember that you must call RasHangUp before your application exits so that the connection is closed cleanly.